How do I use XPathSelect to create a nested data control with a XMLDataSource in ASP.NET?
Whenever I need nested data, I use nested repeaters. In the code behind, on every itemdatabound event of the parent repeater, a new childview is created. Today I came across this article about a XMLDataSource, and it suggests that you can do it much easier. There is a code sample available, but not the corresponding XML file. I have tried to get this to work, but I can't.
Here is my ASP.NET file:
<asp:DataList id="DataList1" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="OrderId" Text='<%# XPath("Order/OrderId") %>' runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:DataList id="DataList2" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("Order/Order_Details") %>' runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate> Product: <%# XPath("Detail/product") %> <br />
                Amount: <%# XPath("Detail/amount") %> <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Datalist>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:XmlDataSource id="XmlDataSource1" XPath="Orders" DataFile="orders.xml" runat="server" />

And this is my XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Orders>  
<Order>  
    <OrderId>Order 1</OrderId>  
    <Order_Details>
        <Detail>  
            <product>product 1</product>  
            <amount>amount 1</amount>  
        </Detail>  
        <Detail>  
            <product>product 2</product>  
            <amount>amount 2</amount>  
        </Detail>
    </Order_Details> 
</Order>      
<Order>  
    <OrderId>Order 2</OrderId>  
    <Order_Details>   
        <Detail>  
            <product>product 3</product>  
            <amount>amount 3</amount>  
        </Detail>  
        <Detail>  
            <product>product 4</product>  
            <amount>amount 4</amount>  
        </Detail>
    </Order_Details> 
</Order>        

The output is:
Order 1
Product: product 1
Amount: amount 1

Product: product 3
Amount: amount 3

This is of course not the desired result. I need two orders with two products each. Am I making some mistake, or do I still have to use additional code?
